# AngularJS dynamic data binding in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object, data-binding, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to call an attribute of an data-binded object dynamically based on the ng-repeat object. I have created a simple setup, can anybody solve this, if it is solvable like this?

The input should get the value of the "person.item". 
For example: person.id  -> 100

http://jsfiddle.net/q7gs3njj/

html

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="TestController">
    <div ng-repeat="item in list">
        <label>{{ item }}:</label>
        <input  type="text"/>
    </div>
    {{list}}
</div>
```

javascript

```
function TestController($scope) {
    $scope.list = [ 'id', 'name', 'gender' ];

    $person = { id:'100', name:'John', age:'22', gender:'Male' };

}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Of course, just use item as index:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="TestController">
    <div ng-repeat="item in list">
        <label>{{ item }}:</label>
        <input  type="text" ng-model="person[item]"/>
    </div>
    {{list}}
</div>
```

And the person must be in the scope:

```
function TestController($scope) {
    $scope.list = [ 'id', 'name', 'gender' ];
    $scope.person = { id:'100', name:'John', age:'22', gender:'Male' };   
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! Tried that before but forgot to add my person to the scope